# Splitting double integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, vector-analysis

I am asked to find the double integral of 2xy dy dx over a region:

[image]

[image]

I have found the equation of some lines.

Between (0,0) and (4,4), y=x

Between (5,0) and (4,4), y = -4x + 20

I am confused as to why I have to split the integral.

Why can't the limits for the integral with respect to x go from 0 to 5, and the integral with respect to y go from y=x to y=-4x + 20?

Thank you for your time, I appreciate any help,
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the outer integral is the one with respect to $x$, the inner integral with respect to $y$ should be $\int_{y=\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)}$, where $y=\alpha(x)$ is the equation of the curve which forms the **lower** boundary of the region, and $y=\beta(x)$ is the equation of the curve which forms the **upper** boundary.

In this case, the line $y=0$ is the lower boundary, so $\alpha(x)=0$, while the lines $y=x$ and $y=20-4x$ form different parts of the upper boundary, so
$$
\beta(x) = \begin{cases}
x,& 0 \le x \le 4,\\
20-4x,& 4 < x \le 5.
\end{cases}
$$
Because of the division into cases in the function $\beta$, you have to split the computation into two integrals (one of which has $x$ as the upper bound in the inner integral, while the other one has $20-4x$ as the upper bound).

If you want to do the integral in one stroke, you can instead take the $y$ integral on the outside (from 0 to 4), and let the bounds on the inner $x$ integral go from the **left** boundary curve $x=y$ to the **right** boundary curve $x=(20-y)/4$.